# Extracting GPG Key Usage Flags via Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, bouncycastle, pgp, gnupg

It appears that while the `PGPPublicKey` class offers an `isEncryptionKey()` method to determine if a public key's algorithm is acceptable for encryption purposes (`RSA_GENERAL`, `RSA_ENCRYPT`, `ELGAMAL_GENERAL`, `ELGAMAL_ENCRYPT`) this alone is not sufficient for selecting a valid encryption subkey.

There is information regarding the intended usage of the public key stored within the packet, as seen in GnuPG packet.h:

```
 41 /* Usage flags */
 42 #define PUBKEY_USAGE_SIG     GCRY_PK_USAGE_SIGN  /* Good for signatures. */
 43 #define PUBKEY_USAGE_ENC     GCRY_PK_USAGE_ENCR  /* Good for encryption. */
 44 #define PUBKEY_USAGE_CERT    GCRY_PK_USAGE_CERT  /* Also good to certify keys.*/
 45 #define PUBKEY_USAGE_AUTH    GCRY_PK_USAGE_AUTH  /* Good for authentication. */
 46 #define PUBKEY_USAGE_UNKNOWN GCRY_PK_USAGE_UNKN  /* Unknown usage flag. */
 47 #define PUBKEY_USAGE_NONE    256                 /* No usage given. */
```

My question is, given that Bouncy Castle does not expose these flags, what is the suggested way to extract this key usage information from a PublicKeyPacket in Java?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out. For posterity, here's the solution:

```
// If Key Usage flags are present, we must respect them:
int keyFlagsEncountered = 0;
boolean keyUsageAllowsEncryption = false;

Iterator<PGPSignature> i = key.getSignatures();
while(i.hasNext()) {
    PGPSignature signature = i.next();
    int keyFlags = signature.getHashedSubPackets().getKeyFlags();
    keyFlagsEncountered += keyFlags;

    boolean isEncryptComms = (keyFlags & KeyFlags.ENCRYPT_COMMS) > 0;
    boolean isEncryptStorage = (keyFlags & KeyFlags.ENCRYPT_STORAGE) > 0;
    // Other KeyFlags available here (AUTHENTICATION, SIGN_DATA, CERTIFY_OTHER).

    if (isEncryptComms || isEncryptStorage) {
        keyUsageAllowsEncryption = true;
    }
}

// However, if Key Usage flags are not present (older key, or key generation process simply did not include the flags) 
// then we still attempt to use an encryption key using the existing methods:
keyUsageAllowsEncryption = keyFlagsEncountered == 0 || keyUsageAllowsEncryption;
```

Comment: Hello from the posterity. Shouldn't it be keyFlags & KeyFlags.ENCRYPT_COMMS == 0 instead of > 0? Thanks.